# Updates for Windows 8 (updated from Windows 7) fail during configuration

Tags: windows-8, windows-update

For several months now my Windows 8 system (German Windows 8, 32bit) fails to install the system updates; the last one which successfully installed was KB2918614, at 2014-09-14 (security update for Windows 8). All further updates failed; as of now, there are 55 updates waiting.  I tried every now and then, giving the self-repair its chance; now that my desktop system has another problem, I want to get my laptop updated, at last.

The system tries to configure the updates; after 98%, it says

```
Fehler beim Konfigurieren der Windows-Updates.
Änderungen werden rückgängig gemacht
Schalten Sie den Computer nicht aus.
```

which can be translated as (I don't know the exact wording of an English version):

```
Error configuring the Windows updates.
Changes are being reverted
Don't switch off the computer.
```

I had a look at the event protocol and found the following updates (sorted for looking them up and uncheck them in the system updates control):

```
KB2973501
KB2979571
KB3003743
KB3011780
KB3034344
KB3035017
KB3039066
```

... which all failed with an 0x800F0922 error.

I unchecked the failed updates and tried again, hoping this would work and I'd be able to install them after a first successful step. This failed; this time there were even more errors.

I tried some repair of the updates database ("Windows Update", "Problembehandlung"):

- Potentieller Fehler der Windows Update-Datenbank erkannt: 0x80070490 (behoben)  (probably "possible error of update database found: 0x80070490 (fixed)")
- Windows Update-Komponenten müssen repariert werden (behoben) (probably "update components need repair (fixed)")

After that, the system had forgotten about all previously installed updates:

- Updates wurden zuletzt gesucht: nie (updates seeked last time: never)
- Updates wurden installiert: nie (updates installed: never)

I tried the installation again, but no luck.

Currently I suspect the cause of the problem to show up in the following line, which occurs very frequently in the log:

- Der Server "{752073A1-23F2-4396-85F0-8FDB879ED0ED}" konnte innerhalb des angegebenen Zeitabschnitts mit DCOM nicht registriert werden.

My translation:

- The Server "{752073A1-23F2-4396-85F0-8FDB879ED0ED}" could not be registered with DCOM during the given time.

I have looked up `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CSLID\{752073A1-23F2-4396-85F0-8FDB879ED0ED}` in the registry, but couldn't find anything obvious to the Windows non-expert.

What can I do to fix my update problem; any pointers? Thank you!

**Edit:**
`sfc /scannow` in an admin shell seemed to do some repair, but didn't fix the problem; the update (54 updates) failed again.

Still the problem with the `{752073A1...}` server, and the same failed updates as above (more below some information lines which I might have missed in the first place).

I found a warning about a component `AFD` and an event 16001:

> Die Beschreibung für die Ereignis-ID "16001" aus der Quelle "AFD" wurde nicht gefunden. Entweder ist die Komponente, die dieses Ereignis auslöst, nicht auf dem lokalen Computer installiert, oder die Installation ist beschädigt. Sie können die Komponente auf dem lokalen Computer installieren oder reparieren.

which could be translated roughly as:

> The description for the event id "16001" from the source "AFD" was not found. Either the component triggering this event is not installed on the local computer, or the installation is damaged. You can install the component to the local computer or repair it.

Additional information, stored with the event:

```
\Device\Afd
\Driver\tcpipBM
```

**Update**: Windows wanted to install 44 updates when I rebooted, and one seems to have succeeded: KB2976978.

Comment: First step.  Run SFC.  Second Step.  Run DISM.  Between these two tools they will fix any integrity problems.  You might want to think about installing `Windows 8.1` the system corruption might be severe enough that it cannot be fixed.

Comment: Ok, currently running `sfc /scannow` in an admin shell; thank you. I have tried to install Windows 8.1, but it failed ...

Comment: You will want to download a `Windows 8.1` .ISO, use a generic `Windows 8.1` key to install it, then change the license key to your `Windows 8.0` key in order to activate the installation.

Comment: I just needed to start over again with `sfc /scannow` - my system had frozen at 40%. - If all repair and/or update fails, I consider saving my configuration to an external hard disk, then install 8.1 on an SSD, then restore the settings. But none of these I have done before ...

Comment: `sfc` has run and seems to have fixed something; the `%SystemRoot%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log` file contained some info, but was rewritten meanwhile by some process. In which regard would `DISM` help me? I tend to retrying the update now.

Comment: Delete or rename the CBS.log; run sfc in safe mode; then use elevated cmd prompt `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"` to throw the main points out to a desktop txt file - or run it on the existing file first

Comment: @Tetsujin: I just re-run `sfc /scannow` and created the details file - 335 lines. The last line says "... Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired", but there are some lines "Cannot repair member file", all refering to "[l:34{17}]"I386\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.2.9200.16430". Now booting into safe mode and retrying.

Comment: share the complete CBS folder (compressed as zip on a cloud service). I'll take a look at the logs.

Comment: Thanks a lot; here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5oj2-wJiTmudWMxYkJXS3JoNTA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok, I posted a solution.

Comment: @Tobias - DISM repairs the files located within your `WinSxS` directory.  SFC uses this directory to repair your actual system files.  So if you have corruption within the `WinSxS` directory then SFC will fail with cryptic messages.  Despite the odd choice in argument names, the DISM `/Online` argument, does not check the internet its references the "online system, current system, the running system" in other words the Windows installation currently running.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for the explanation. Seems I didn't need `DISM` in this case; my problem is solved. Meanwhile I even updated to Windows 8.1, and installed all current updates :-)

Comment: @Tobias - The comment was for the future so you knew what it does and for everyone else.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, of course.

Comment: @Ramhound DISM can't fix such a configuration issue. So, checking the log is always the first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows fails to register ETW events for Win32k.sys:

```
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Info                  CSI    000000d1 Begin executing advanced installer phase 38 (0x00000026) index 126 (0x0000007e) (sequence 165)
    Old component: [ml:294{147},l:292{146}]"Microsoft-Windows-Win32k, Culture=neutral, Version=6.2.9200.17096, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=x86, versionScope=NonSxS"
    New component: [ml:294{147},l:292{146}]"Microsoft-Windows-Win32k, Culture=neutral, Version=6.2.9200.17287, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=x86, versionScope=NonSxS"
    Install mode: install
    Installer ID: {3bb9fd2b-351e-4b9c-b1fc-ed0758805998}
    Installer name: [6]"Events"
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Error                 CSI    00000001 (F) Logged @2015/3/17:21:38:28.243 : [ml:258{129},l:256{128}]"events installer: online=1, install=1, component=x86_Microsoft-Windows-Win32k_31bf3856ad364e35_6.2.9200.17287_neutral_release__."
[gle=0x80004005]
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Error                 CSI    00000002 (F) Logged @2015/3/17:21:38:28.321 : [ml:240{120},l:238{119}]"EventAITrace:Provider Microsoft-Windows-Win32k is already installed with GUID {e7ef96be-969f-414f-97d7-3ddb7b558ccc}.

"
[gle=0x80004005]
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Error                 CSI    00000003 (F) Logged @2015/3/17:21:38:28.321 : [ml:168{84},l:166{83}]"WmiCmiPlugin manproc.cpp(683): InstrumentationManifestAssert failed. HR=0x80073aa2."
[gle=0x80004005]
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Error                 CSI    00000004 (F) Logged @2015/3/17:21:38:28.321 : [ml:166{83},l:164{82}]"WmiCmiPlugin eventloghandler.cpp(192): ProcessEventsInstall failed. HR=0x80073aa2."
[gle=0x80004005]
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Error                 CSI    00000005 (F) Logged @2015/3/17:21:38:28.321 : [ml:170{85},l:168{84}]"WmiCmiPlugin eventloghandler.cpp(212): EventLogHandlerInstall failed. HR=0x80073aa2."
[gle=0x80004005]
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Error                 CSI    00000006@2015/3/17:21:38:28.336 (F) CMIADAPTER: Inner Error Message from AI HRESULT = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(15010)
 [
[22]"Konfigurationsfehler

"
]
[gle=0x80004005]
2015-03-17 22:38:28, Error                 CSI    00000007@2015/3/17:21:38:28.336 (F) CMIADAPTER: AI failed. HRESULT = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(15010)
```

[The resolution to this problem](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2014/11/10/what-to-do-if-you-experience-a-rollback-when-installing-kb3000061.aspx) is to:

- **Export** and then **delete** the following registry key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WINEVT\Publishers{e7ef96be-969f-414f-97d7-3ddb7b558ccc}**
- Reboot the system
- try to run Windows Update again.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I deleted the key; I rebooted, and verified it didn't re-appear; I started the update. After a few seconds, something seems to have been installed, but no entry in the updates history. Started again; now the 54 updates are being downloaded again (still "0 KB total, 0 % completed"); proceeding ...

Comment: This has worked!

Comment: nice to hear that it helped.

Comment: This also resolved my issue with a particular update failing on a Win7->Win8 upgraded machine - "Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x80073AA2: Security Update for Windows 8 (KB3034344)."

Comment: @magicandre1981, I am having a similar problem with Windows 7 updater reporting the error 0x80070490 - would removal of this same (or another) HKEY resolve the issue? I am currently running sfc/scannow and waiting for the results per this question: http://superuser.com/q/1176907/630402 Your input and assistance would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy look in your CBS.log if you also see the line **00000002 (F) Logged @2015/3/17:21:38:28.321 : [ml:240{120},l:238{119}]"EventAITrace:Provider Microsoft-Windows-Win32k is already installed with GUID {e7ef96be-969f-414f-97d7-3ddb7b558ccc}** if yes, delete this key.

Comment: @magicandre1981 `PS C:\Windows\Logs\CBS> cat CBS.log | grep "{e7ef96be-969f-414f-97d7-3ddb7b558ccc}"` returns nothing (I am assuming I am using grep correctly) - thanks tho!

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy in this case it is a different key. look in the log which issue you have